# Mysql before and after multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck  on a query. I'm searching for one customers reviews within their notes, but I need it to return the note before, including and after the ones that it finds with this query:

```
SELECT ct.whn, ct.tpe, ct.drctn, ct.smmry, ct.dscrptn, ct.zxcrtdby,
(SELECT nme FROM sdcrdtr WHERE sdcrdtr.id = ct.crdtr) as 'Creditor Name',
(SELECT accntrfrnce FROM cddbt WHERE cddbt.id = ct.dbt) as Reference

FROM cdcntct ct, cdcse c

WHERE c.id = ct.cse AND c.rfrnce = '123456789'
AND ct.smmry LIKE '%review%'
```

I've seen similar questions on here but it's for finding all in a row from a table where you provide a specific ID or similar.

I can't find where to begin!

Thanks in advance.
Will

EDIT: Sample date

```
ID    WhN         SMMRY            DSCRPTN
12    01/05/2015  Sent Paperwork   Info Received
13    01/05/2014  Reviewed         Some Info Received
14    28/04/2014  Spoke to Client  Said hello
15    01/05/2013  Note 15          Blank
16    01/05/2012  Note 16          Blank
17    01/05/2011  Review done      Blank
18    30/12/2010  Another note     Blank
```

So If I was to run my query but with the request for the rows before, including and after, it would return ID's 12,13,14 and then 16,17,18. Whereas it currently only returns ID's 13 and 17 as I don't know where to add in this clause.

Comment: Please provide schema and sample data.

Comment: I've added in some sample data, I'm unsure what you mean by provide the schema, sorry. It's a MySQL database.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select t2.* 
from MyTable t2
inner join (
  select t.ID, max(tb.ID) as ID_Before, min(ta.ID) as ID_After
  from MyTable t
  left join MyTable tb on tb.ID < t.ID
  left join MyTable ta on ta.ID > t.ID
  where t.SMMRY like '%review%'
  group by t.ID
) a on t2.ID in (a.ID, a.ID_Before, a.ID_After)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b217/28)

```
| ID |        WhN |           SMMRY |            DSCRPTN |
|----|------------|-----------------|--------------------|
| 12 | 01/05/2015 |  Sent Paperwork |      Info Received |
| 13 | 01/05/2014 |        Reviewed | Some Info Received |
| 14 | 28/04/2014 | Spoke to Client |         Said hello |
| 16 | 01/05/2012 |         Note 16 |              Blank |
| 17 | 01/05/2011 |     Review done |              Blank |
| 18 | 30/12/2010 |    Another note |              Blank |
```